# Mongo query to group and calculate average with group by

Tags: mongodb, average

I have a mongo collection mytopic with the following structure:

```
id : ObjectId
host: String
analytics: Object
    topic_count : Array
         name: String
         mentions: Int
         duration: Float
         percentage: Float
```

I want to group by analytics.topic_count.name and return the average of duration for each user.
My expected output is :

```
Topic1:      User1: <Average of duration for Topic1>
             User2: <float>
             User3: <float>
             User4: <float>
             User5: <float>

Topic2       User1: <float>
             User2: <float>
             User3: <float>
             User4: <float>
             User5: <float>
```

is it possible to get this kind of output. I am new to mongo and totally lost on this query. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Here is a partial export of my db collection:

```
    [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5edfd7a9c7152c8e6c708482"
  },
  "host": "user1",
  "analytics": {
    "topic_count": [
      {
        "name": "Topic1",
        "mentions": 12,
        "duration": 160.94,
        "percentage": 5.76
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic4",
        "mentions": 9,
        "duration": 108.14,
        "percentage": 3.87
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic3",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 48.52,
        "percentage": 1.74
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic2",
        "mentions": 8,
        "duration": 95.5,
        "percentage": 3.42
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic5",
        "mentions": 2,
        "duration": 2.43,
        "percentage": 0.09
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic6",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 55.75,
        "percentage": 1.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic7",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 53.33,
        "percentage": 1.91
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic8",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 45.37,
        "percentage": 1.62
      }
    ]
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5edfd7a9c7152c8e6c708483"
  },
  "host": "user1",
  "analytics": {
    "topic_count": [
      {
        "name": "Topic1",
        "mentions": 14,
        "duration": 209.85,
        "percentage": 7.13
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic4",
        "mentions": 9,
        "duration": 97.27,
        "percentage": 3.31
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic3",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 37.13,
        "percentage": 1.26
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic2",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 52.46,
        "percentage": 1.78
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic5",
        "mentions": 2,
        "duration": 3.13,
        "percentage": 0.11
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic6",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 34,
        "percentage": 1.16
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic7",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 79.9,
        "percentage": 2.72
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic8",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 87.45,
        "percentage": 2.97
      }
    ]
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5edfd7a9c7152c8e6c708484"
  },
  "host": "user1",
  "analytics": {
    "topic_count": [
      {
        "name": "Topic1",
        "mentions": 12,
        "duration": 165.19,
        "percentage": 5.91
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic4",
        "mentions": 9,
        "duration": 112.15,
        "percentage": 4.01
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic3",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 29.28,
        "percentage": 1.05
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic2",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 46.74,
        "percentage": 1.67
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic5",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 2.7,
        "percentage": 0.1
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic6",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 17.59,
        "percentage": 0.63
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic7",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 62.34,
        "percentage": 2.23
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic8",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 57.62,
        "percentage": 2.06
      }
    ]
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5edfd7a9c7152c8e6c708485"
  },
  "host": "user1",
  "analytics": {
    "topic_count": [
      {
        "name": "Topic1",
        "mentions": 12,
        "duration": 226.65,
        "percentage": 6.04
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic4",
        "mentions": 9,
        "duration": 139.59,
        "percentage": 3.72
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic3",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 44.85,
        "percentage": 1.2
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic2",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 69.18,
        "percentage": 1.84
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic5",
        "mentions": 2,
        "duration": 18.07,
        "percentage": 0.48
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic6",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 63.9,
        "percentage": 1.7
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic7",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 57.19,
        "percentage": 1.52
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic8",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 60.42,
        "percentage": 1.61
      }
    ]
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5edfd7a9c7152c8e6c708486"
  },
  "host": "user1",
  "analytics": {
    "topic_count": [
      {
        "name": "Topic1",
        "mentions": 12,
        "duration": 181.99,
        "percentage": 6.31
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic4",
        "mentions": 9,
        "duration": 102.66,
        "percentage": 3.56
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic3",
        "mentions": 3,
        "duration": 33.21,
        "percentage": 1.15
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic2",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 55.31,
        "percentage": 1.92
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic5",
        "mentions": 5,
        "duration": 9.24,
        "percentage": 0.32
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic6",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 35.82,
        "percentage": 1.24
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic7",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 72.24,
        "percentage": 2.51
      },
      {
        "name": "Topic8",
        "mentions": 4,
        "duration": 30.3,
        "percentage": 1.05
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$analytics.topic_count"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        topic: "$analytics.topic_count.name",
        host: "$host"
      },
      "duration": {
        "$avg": "$analytics.topic_count.duration"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.topic",
      "durations": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            {
              "host": "$_id.host"
            },
            {
              "duration": "$duration"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is working [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ON3EZ5OlHB6)

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.